# Having issues with user Authorisation/Authentication with React Context. How do I access the variables in a class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-hooks, passport.js

So I am using React Context and Hooks for the first time. I followed a YouTube tutorial and I have user authorisation and authentication working, however I am really struggling to figure out how to access the active user and if this user is authenticated with class components. The tutorial I followed only used React Hooks and I have a mix of hooks and class components for my project.
In the Code I have provided below, if we look at the NavBar class, it can easily check if the user authenticated as this is a hook component. I want to be able to do this for class components such as App.js and Step1.js. In App.js I have tried this using the context api documentation.

```
 const Auth = this.context;
    console.log(Auth);
```

However, this just returns a null set. Am I missing a consumer tag, or should the provider tag be somewhere else? I would greatly appreciate any help or advice!

AuthContext.js

```
import React, {createContext,useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import AuthService from '../Services/AuthService';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export default ({ children })=>{
    const [user,setUser] = useState(null);
    const [isAuthenticated,setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [isLoaded,setIsLoaded] = useState(true);

    useEffect(()=>{
        AuthService.isAuthenticated().then(data =>{
            setUser(data.user);
            setIsAuthenticated(data.isAuthenticated);
            setIsLoaded(true);
        });
    },[]);

    return (
        <div>
            {!isLoaded ? <h1>Loading</h1> : 
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{user,setUser,isAuthenticated,setIsAuthenticated}}>
                { children }
            </AuthContext.Provider>}
        </div>
    )
            }
```

AuthService.js

```
export default {
  login: user => {
    return fetch("/api/login", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data);
  },

  register: user => {
    return fetch("/api/register2", {
      method: "post",
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data);
  },

  logout: () => {
    return fetch("/api/logout")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => data);
  },

  isAuthenticated: () => {
    return fetch("api/authenticated").then(res => {
      if (res.status != 401) return res.json().then(data => data);
      else return { isAuthenticated: false, user: { username: "", role: "" } };
    });
  }
};
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component, useContext } from "react";
import { getFromStorage, setInStorage } from "../../utils/storage";
import Navbar from "../NavBar";
import Header from "../Header/Header";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link,
  withRouter,
  Redirect,
  useRouteMatch,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "../Home/Home";
import SideBar from "../SideBar";
import Step1 from "../SafetyPlan/Step1";
import AllSteps from "../SafetyPlan/AllSteps";
import PatientHome from "../Patient/PatientHome";
import HeaderOut from "../Header/HeaderOut";
import AddPatient from "../Patient/AddPatient";
import Step2 from "../SafetyPlan/Step2"
import SignUp from "../Register";
import Login from "../Login";
import PrivateRoute from "../HOCs/PrivateRoute";
import UnPrivateRoute from "../HOCs/PrivateRoute";
import AuthContext from '../..//Context/AuthContext'


//I want to be able to access isAuthenticated and user within this class
//I have not sure how to access them. I understand that It is possible but I am struggling to get it to work.
//The NavBar class makes use these hooks in the way I want to. It is a good example I want to look at.

class App extends React.Component {

  //Equivalent to useContext() for functional components
  static contextType = AuthContext;
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token: ""
    };
  }

 
  render() {    
    //Access context using this.context (similar to this.props)
    const Auth = this.context;
    console.log(Auth);

    return (
      // This is your Context Provider (should wrap all other components that require context)
      <AuthContext> 
        {/* The way you designed it, all children will be Context Consumers (see AuthContext.js) */}
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <SideBar></SideBar>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={SignUp} />
            <Route exact path="/Step1" component={Step1} />
            <Route exact path="/Step2" component={Step2} />
            <Route exact path="/AllSteps" component={AllSteps} />
            <Route exact path="/AddPatient" component={AddPatient} />
            <Route exact path="/Register" component={SignUp} />
            <Route exact path="/Login" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/PatientHome/:id" component={PatientHome} />
          </Switch>
          )
        </div>
      </Router>
      </AuthContext>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

NavBar.js

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthService from '../Services/AuthService';
import { AuthContext } from '../Context/AuthContext';



const Navbar = props =>{
    const {isAuthenticated,user,setIsAuthenticated,setUser} = useContext(AuthContext);
    console.log(isAuthenticated);
    console.log(user);
    const onClickLogoutHandler = ()=>{
        AuthService.logout().then(data=>{
            if(data.success){
                setUser(data.user);
                setIsAuthenticated(false);
            }
        });
    }

    const unauthenticatedNavBar = ()=>{
        return (
            <>
                <Link to="/">
                    <li className="nav-item nav-link">
                        Home
                    </li>
                </Link>  
                <Link to="/login">
                    <li className="nav-item nav-link">
                        Login
                    </li>
                </Link>  
                <Link to="/register">
                    <li className="nav-item nav-link">
                        Register
                    </li>
                </Link>  
            </>
        )
    }

    const authenticatedNavBar = ()=>{
        return(
            <>
                <Link to="/">
                    <li className="nav-item nav-link">
                        Home
                    </li>
                </Link> 
                <Link to="/todos">
                    <li className="nav-item nav-link">
                        Todos
                    </li>
                </Link> 
                {
                    user.role === "admin" ? 
                    <Link to="/admin">
                        <li className="nav-item nav-link">
                            Admin
                        </li>
                    </Link> : null
                }  
                <button type="button" 
                        className="btn btn-link nav-item nav-link" 
                        onClick={onClickLogoutHandler}>Logout</button>
            </>
        )
    }
    return(
        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <Link to="/">
                <div className="navbar-brand">SafePlan View</div>
            </Link>
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
                <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    { !isAuthenticated ? unauthenticatedNavBar() : authenticatedNavBar()}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default Navbar;
```

Step1.js

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import axios from "axios";
import { getFromStorage, setInStorage } from "../../utils/storage";
import AuthContext from './/..//..//Context/AuthContext'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  withRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Form,
  Button,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  ControlLabel
} from "react-bootstrap";
import Home from "../Home/Home";
const GridWrapper = styled.div`
  p {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  h3 {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  margin-top: 4em;
  margin-left: 28em;
  margin-right: 1em;
`;

class Step1 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      token: "",
      session: 0,
      date: "",
      versions: [],
      warnings: [],
      emailOfEditor: "Hello",
      purpose: [],
      privateBenefit: "wewewe",
      achievablePlan: "wewewewe",
      purposeEvidence: "ewewe",
      achievablePlanEvidence: "wewe",
      privateBenefitEvidence: "wewewew",
      charityName: "",
      time: ""
    };
  }
  static contextType = AuthContext;

  updateInput = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  getPatientId = (event, { value }) => {
    console.log(value);
    let bird_name = event.target.textContent;
    console.log(bird_name);
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    const obj = getFromStorage("the_main_app");
    if (obj && obj.token) {
      const { token } = obj; // Verify token
      fetch("/api/account/verify?token=" + token)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          if (json.success) {
            this.setState({
              token,
              isLoading: false
            });
          } else {
            this.setState({
              isLoading: false
            });
          }
        });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false
      });
    }
    axios.get("/api/getStep1").then(res => {
      const warnings = res.data
      this.setState({ warnings });
      console.log(warnings);
    });
  }

  generateNewSession = e => {
    var that = this;
    let sessionNum = Math.floor(100000 + Math.random() * 900000);
    this.setState({ session: sessionNum });
    this.setState({ date: new Date().toLocaleString() });
    console.log(this.state.session);
    console.log(this.state.date);
    const { warning } = this.state;

    // Post request to backend
    fetch("/api/updateSession", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        warning: warning
      })
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log("json", json);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { versions } = this.state;
    const { token } = this.state;
    
      return (
        <GridWrapper>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-10">
              <div className="card" style={{ backgroundColor: "#f0923c" }}>
                <div className="card">
                  <div className="card-body" style={{ paddingTop: "10px" }}>
                    <h3 style={{ fontWeight: "" }}>
                      {" "}
                      Step 1: Warning Signs (thoughts, images, mood, situation,
                      behaviour) that a crisis may be developing
                    </h3>

                    <ul style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}>
                      {this.state.warnings.map(warning => (
                        <li>{warning.signDesc}</li>
                      ))}
                    </ul>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-2">
              <Link to>
                <div style={{ color: "#f0923c" }}>Next Step</div>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </GridWrapper>
      );
    }

  
  
}
export default Step1;
```

Comment: You want to know how to check if the user is logged in or not right?

Comment: Yes, So I want to be able to check isAuthenticated and the user variables in class components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically when the user logs in, you should be returned with a Security token key, most common would be JWT(JSON Web Token), you should store this token in `localstorage` or `cachestorage` and retrieve this in your components and see if the user is authenticated or not. If you don't have proper implementation of JWT, then you can for now use a boolean variable and check if the user is logged in.

You should have protected Route setup. I'm attaching you the snippet to store values in localstorage.

**loginComponent**

```
  if(postLogin(user)){
    localStorage.setItem('token',true);
}
```

Create PrivateRoute, And then in PrivateRoute,
check if user login exists or not and based on it redirect.

```
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
import React from "react";

const Route = require("react-router-dom").Route;
export const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (<Route {...rest} render={props => (
        localStorage.getItem('token') ? (
            <Component {...props}/>
        ) : (
            <Redirect push to={{
                pathname: '/login',   //whatever your component is
                from: props.location
            }}/>
        )
    )}/>)
};
```

In your App.js

```
import {PrivateRoute} from './PrivateRoute'
.
.
.
 <PrivateRoute exact path={"/home/posts"} component={Posts} />  //User cannot access this component without being logged in.
```

> Note: Make sure to clear the localStorage or cacheStorage through user logout.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! One thing that keeps crossing my mind is how to let React know that we logged out. When we remove the 'token' from localStorage it won't trigger a rerender. We should somehow store this in a state variable at the top of the component hierarchy. When that is the case, it gets difficult to update the state from `AuthService` which itself is not a React component.